# get "alphabetical" next unicode character in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, couchdb, icu

I need to be able to find the immediately following character for a given character in the [ICU collation algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/) in python.

My use case is that I am querying keys in a no-sql db that uses that algorithm for sorting and I need all keys starting with a set of characters.

What I'm looking for is a function:

```
def nextchar(x):
    return x[:-1]+next_in_icu(x[-1:])
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input and expected output.

Comment: that's the one thank you ! I did not know that base function. If you want to put that as an answer I'll validate it.

Answer (score 0):

Some background information first, then a possible solution.

ICU uses the CLDR Collation Algorithm, a tailoring of the Unicode Collation Algorithm. The base collation rules in CLDR are referred to as the root collation.

Language specific tailorings contain minimal changes to the root collation. So any ICU collator instance will support all of Unicode. Within each sequence, there are multiple collation strengths, so attempting to do what you want based on collation keys would be complex and inefficient.

ICU also has an AlphabeticIndex class, but this would be too coarse for your needs.

Probably the best fit would be CLDR's exemplar characters for each locale. I will base my suggestion on exemplar characters. I am making the assumption that supplementary characters are not needed.

```
import icu
def get_next_char(x, lang):
    exemplarSet = icu.LocaleData(lang).getExemplarSet(0, 0)
    characters = list(exemplarSet)
    if x is None:
        return characters[0]
    index = characters.index(x.lower())
    return characters[index+1]

def nextchars(x, lang):
    result = x + get_next_char(None, lang) if len(x) == 1 else x[:-1]+get_next_char(x[-1:], lang)
    return  result
```

The `get_next_char()` takes two arguments, the character you are trying to find the next of, and the language. You need to use a language tag rather than a locale object.

This will create a UnicodeSet object containing a set, similar in context to a regular expression set.

Then convert the UnicodeSet to a list, the ranges in the set are converted to a sequence of individual characters during typecasting to a list.

Find the index of the character and then find the next character in the list.

I haven't bothered with error handling in the example, that is something that will need to be added.

Examples:

```
nextchars('fin', 'en')
# 'fio'
nextchars('str', 'en')
# 'sts'
nextchars("b", "en")
'ba'
```

Assuming I have understood your question correctly.